# What type of data can transit between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, types, named-pipes

I have 2 applications that have to communicate.
Both of the application are on the same computer, this is why I'm using a Named Pipe to communicate.

My question is about the datas that are going to be send. What are my options?
Does the following possibilities are feasible?

- Send Byte between the 2 applications
- Send C Struct
- Send some protocol buffer objects

I'm open if there is some other ideas, my objective is to have something really fast to implement.

Comment: You mean one will be C# and the other C++, both running in their own process?

Comment: If both programs were C or C++, then sending raw C structures would be a good alternative, but in your case you have to use some form of serialization. Protocol buffers offers one way to do that.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yeah I'll have 2 applications running in 2 different process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah i was expecting this answer, I was still hoping that i could share C struct in C#, but i'll User Thrift or protocol buffer and since I have already used both i shouldn't be too long to get it working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except if you need very high performance, I would go for a standard cross-language service communication language like [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) or [Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

This will allow you to scale without issues if one day you have to communicate with a third application in another language or if you decide to run each services on a different machine.

Comment: I'm going to do this, and since I'm already using Thrift for the RPC functionnality with another component it should be easy to implement!!

Answer (score 1):

Really fast to (for you to) implement, or really fast in operation?

If the former - go with a web service, gsoap or WCF will make you a simple interface you can call.

If the latter, you probably want shared memory - put your raw data in there and allow the other process to read it out. If you have lots of data to transfer this is the way to go. If you have minor amounts, then you could just send it directly over a named pipe (or a socket, always good, easy to use and will let you migrate to multiple machines much more easily).

To interpret the data that you're transferring, forget trying to send a C# object and have the C++ side read it in as the same object, you're going to have to deal with the raw data. This means serialising the data in some format (a binary format works well too BTW and will be a lot faster than, say, serialising it to XML). The other side can then read this in and un-serialise it into its own data structures.

Answer (score 1):

One option:
Use [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) for transport, and protobuf, thrift or even json as the communication language.
Zeromq is really fast.

Comment: Zeromq seems really interresting but I don't have time to learn some new stuff and since my IPC has to be on the same computer named pipe is the way to go for me!